# Postfix no longer receiving email

Tags: postfix-mta

My web server and mail server are one in the same and are on an AWS server.  I set up postfix to route email to from my domain to my ISP email address.  It has worked fine for many months.  Recently, an SSL certificate was installed for my webserver and now I am unable to receive email.  However I can still send email from the linux user account for which mail should be forwarded just fine.  AWS is set up to receive SMTP connections on port 25 and SMTPS on port 465.    I'm pretty sure the problem is with the SSL certificate, but not sure of the exact issue.  It is a wild card SSL Cert.  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure this out? We have the same issue and it is an emergency for us to fix it and I am not finding anything in my searches.

Answer (score 0):

I simply just restarted the server.  That worked for me.